# Dependency resolution fails on Gradle 5.1

Tags: java, gradle

I am facing an issue with my gradle project during migration to Gradle 5.1 from Gradle 4.10.2 :

**Issue :**

```
./gradlew clean build
> Task :subprojects:lib-abc-admin:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':subprojects:lib-abc-admin:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':subprojects:lib-abc-admin:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:.
     Required by:
         project :subprojects:lib-abc-admin   

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

In previous version Gradle 4.10.2, this error was getting circumvented by the following switch:

```
enableFeaturePreview("IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT")
```

But in gradle 5 this switch has been deprecated, seems like this doesn't work anymore and I am getting the errors.

**Any alternatives / suggestions / solutions ?**

```
Toolchain Details :

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.0
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13-LTS)
OS:           Linux 4.19.8-200.fc28.x86_64 amd64
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide the `build.gradle` for further investigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From gradle [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8218):

Different approaches were tried for supporting BOMs.

In Gradle 5.0, through feedback from the community (see [#4422](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4422)), we ended up deciding on an explicit notation to import a BOM.

So you will need to update dependencies on modules that are BOMs to that notation.

See [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import) for details.

And since the `IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT` feature is now enabled by default, you can remove the `enableFeaturePreview("IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT")` line from your settings.gradle(.kts)